# Build next ViewPager fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

well, I'm building an app which uses the android.support.v4.view.ViewPager in the MainActivity. I load some video adresses by a JSON object from a server and want to create a fragment for every video (to swipe to the next one).

My fragment.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

/>
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"

  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I get the following problem: I want to render the next fragments, so that the user can see some preview images if he slides to the next one. At this moment, I can only see a ImageView if onPageScrolled() was done.

That is my way to get access to the fragment Views:

```
VideoFragment obj = (VideoFragment) pageAdapter.getItem(arg0);
VideoView meinVideo = (VideoView) obj.getView().findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
```

Following happens: If I try to get access to item 10, I get a nullpointer exception, but the item exists in pageAdapter. Problem is this line:

```
VideoView meinVideo = (VideoView) obj.getView().findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
```

It only works, if the fragment was already rendered, f.e. after onPageSelected event.

Is there any way to force a render for the next Fragments, so that they were already built before the user swipes?

Comment: Try calling this on your viewpager:         
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(<number that you want to be loaded at a time>);

Comment: Just tried that. Everything works for the first 3 scrolls, after that, I get only a black screen and a OutOfRange error.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason is your VideoFragment not initialized,the VideoFragment's `onCreateView` has not invoked.the default initalize number is 3.